# Pass offset arguments into lm function

Tags: r, expression, offset, lm, coefficients

I am doing a linear regression and I would like to fix some inputs. I have found the way to do this with `offset`. Let's see it in example:

```
set.seed(145)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10), d = rnorm(10))

summary(lm(formula = a ~ . + offset(0.1*c) - c + offset(0.05*d) - d, data = df))
```

The problem is that I have much more variables and I would like to generate my lm formula automatically.

Let's say, I want to pass the names of inputs (that are columns of data in lm) and a value for it's coefs, for example in the next way:

```
inputs_fix <- c("c", "d")
inputs_fix_coef <- c(0.1, 0.05)
```

Then I need a function that writes me a formula as above but I don't know how to write an expression `offset(0.1*c) - c + offset(0.05*d) - d` having `inputs_fix` and `inputs_fix_coef` objects.

Is it possible? There is another way to fix coefficients (more elegant)? Appreciate any help

**UPDATE**: creating formula with `paste` and `as.formula` with @Jan van der Laan suggestion

```
my.formula <- paste0(" + offset(", inputs_fix_coef, "*", inputs_fix, ") - ", inputs_fix, collapse = " ")
lm.fit <- lm(formula = as.formula(paste0("a ~ .", mi.expresion)), data = df))
```

It isn't so clear but it saves all the inputs into lm object `lm.fit$model` that are lost in @Jan van der Laan answer. And don't need to duplicate a data.frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of handling this would be to calculate a new column with your total offset and remove the columns used in your offset from the data set:

```
# create copy of data withou columns used in offset
dat <- df[-match(inputs_fix, names(df))]

# calculate offset
dat$offset <- 0
for (i in seq_along(inputs_fix)) 
  dat$offset <- dat$offset + df[[inputs_fix[i]]]*inputs_fix_coef[i]

# run regression
summary(lm(formula = a ~ . + offset(offset) - offset, data = dat))
```

It is also always possible to generate your formula as a character vector (using `paste` etc) and then convert is to formula object using `as.formula`, but I suspect the solution above is cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I have found a way to create a formula after your suggestion. Add it in update

Comment: You can also use matrix multiplication instead of a loop: `dat$offset <-as.matrix(df[inputs_fix]) %*% inputs_fix_coef`